# How disable the blue boundary box when a touch occurs on chrome mobile?

Tags: html, css

I would like to get rid of the blue rectangle for touch visual feedback on my web application. It's always get very unpleasant on rounded button.

[image]

The button above has a css to make it rounded and an active state color. I don't need the native chrome mobile visual feedback.

I also notices that this behaviour does not happens when using bootstrap, but happens when use Bulma or tailwind.

How can I disable this feature in my mobile website?

Comment: It probably has to do with focus. Does it go away when you select a text field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set **-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent** or **-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)** to remove the default hightlight tap color on chrome.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color

About bootstrap, the default css contains the property, as you can see here:
[image]